# apache http redirect appending '/' automatically

Tags: apache

I am trying to redirect all request to my website from http to https. 
It works fine but if a user key in http://example.com/ in the browser window manually it get redirected to https://example.com// why does an extra '/' is being added to the end of the URL.

My apache config file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```